# Get all points within a Triangle

Tags: c#, polygon, fill

I have three points, for example:

```
Start 194 171
Right 216 131
Left  216 203
```

I want to get all the points within that triangle. How would I do that efficiently?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: See if this suits you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771670/calculate-pixels-within-a-polygon
Interesting question that I'm facing myself.

Comment: The key word you need for your Google search is "rasterization". A search for "triangle rasterization" yields some decent-looking results, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*see [z3nth10n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53730713/1282539) for better input validation*

**Introduction:**

The general idea was to get the triangle's edges (y-Wise) for every x in it's range, and then you have all the y's that exist within the triangle for every single x, which with simple conversion turns into all points within the triangle.

You can look at it as if you cut the triangle into stripes, each being of width 1.
So for X=0, on the line between A and B, the Y is 6, and on the line between A and C, the Y is -2, so you can see that the stripe of X=0 is between -2 and 6. Therefore, you can tell that (0, -2) (0, -1) (0, 0) ... (0, 5) (0, 6) are all in the triangle. Doing that for X's between the smallest and the largest within the triangle, and you have all the points in the triangle!

**Speed:**

> For the triangle **(0, 0) (1, 8) (4, 6)** - found **16 points.**
>
> Done **1,000,000 times in 3.68 seconds.**

**Implementation:**

```
public IEnumerable<Point> PointsInTriangle(Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt3)
{
    if (pt1.Y == pt2.Y && pt1.Y == pt3.Y)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The given points must form a triangle.");
    }

    Point tmp;

    if (pt2.X < pt1.X)
    {
        tmp = pt1;
        pt1 = pt2;
        pt2 = tmp;
    }

    if (pt3.X < pt2.X)
    {
        tmp = pt2;
        pt2 = pt3;
        pt3 = tmp;

        if (pt2.X < pt1.X)
        {
            tmp = pt1;
            pt1 = pt2;
            pt2 = tmp;
        }
    }

    var baseFunc = CreateFunc(pt1, pt3);
    var line1Func = pt1.X == pt2.X ? (x => pt2.Y) : CreateFunc(pt1, pt2);

    for (var x = pt1.X; x < pt2.X; x++)
    {
        int maxY;
        int minY = GetRange(line1Func(x), baseFunc(x), out maxY);

        for (var y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
        {
            yield return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

    var line2Func = pt2.X == pt3.X ? (x => pt2.Y) : CreateFunc(pt2, pt3);

    for (var x = pt2.X; x <= pt3.X; x++)
    {
        int maxY;
        int minY = GetRange(line2Func(x), baseFunc(x), out maxY);

        for (var y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
        {
            yield return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}

private int GetRange(double y1, double y2, out int maxY)
{
    if (y1 < y2)
    {
        maxY = (int)Math.Floor(y2);
        return (int)Math.Ceiling(y1);
    }

    maxY = (int)Math.Floor(y1);
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(y2);
}

private Func<int, double> CreateFunc(Point pt1, Point pt2)
{
    var y0 = pt1.Y;

    if (y0 == pt2.Y)
    {
        return x => y0;
    }

    var m = (double)(pt2.Y - y0) / (pt2.X - pt1.X);

    return x => m * (x - pt1.X) + y0;
}
```

Comment: Haha this made me laugh. Respect.

Comment: @KevinWang Oh, I see you've found my easter egg on the 12th pixel? Now, really, what?

Comment: Excellent stuff! This has helped me out tremendously.

Comment: Just a small correction: Since `pt1.X` (for example) is a `double`, the for loops should start like this: `for (var x = Convert.ToInt32(pt1.X); x < pt2.X; x++)` because `line1Func(x)` expects an `int`.

Comment: @SimpleVar - I don't see the Easter Egg.  Sure, once it's pointed out ... It'll be obvious.

Comment: @tobeypeters I don't see the easter egg either. I guess Kevin just found this amusing at the time

Answer (score 3):

[@SimpleVar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1282539/simplevar) answer is well, but it lacks a good check for valid triangles. (This can cause an overflow problem).

So I do my own implementation for Unity3D:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PointsInTriangle<T>(T pt1, T pt2, T pt3)
   where T : IPoint
{
    /*
         // https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-triangle-valid-not-sides-given/
         a + b > c
         a + c > b
         b + c > a
     */

    float a = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(pt1.x, pt1.y), new Vector2(pt2.x, pt2.y)),
          b = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(pt2.x, pt2.y), new Vector2(pt3.x, pt3.y)),
          c = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(pt3.x, pt3.y), new Vector2(pt1.x, pt1.y));

    if (a + b <= c || a + c <= b || b + c <= a)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"The given points must form a triangle. {{{pt1}, {pt2}, {pt3}}}");
        yield break;
    }

    if (TriangleArea(pt1, pt2, pt3) <= 1)
    {
        Point center = GetTriangleCenter(pt1, pt2, pt3);
        yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), center.x, center.y);

        return;
    }

    T tmp;

    if (pt2.x < pt1.x)
    {
        tmp = pt1;
        pt1 = pt2;
        pt2 = tmp;
    }

    if (pt3.x < pt2.x)
    {
        tmp = pt2;
        pt2 = pt3;
        pt3 = tmp;

        if (pt2.x < pt1.x)
        {
            tmp = pt1;
            pt1 = pt2;
            pt2 = tmp;
        }
    }

    var baseFunc = CreateFunc(pt1, pt3);
    var line1Func = pt1.x == pt2.x ? (x => pt2.y) : CreateFunc(pt1, pt2);

    for (var x = pt1.x; x < pt2.x; ++x)
    {
        int maxY;
        int minY = GetRange(line1Func(x), baseFunc(x), out maxY);

        for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; ++y)
            yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), x, y);
    }

    var line2Func = pt2.x == pt3.x ? (x => pt2.y) : CreateFunc(pt2, pt3);

    for (var x = pt2.x; x <= pt3.x; ++x)
    {
        int maxY;
        int minY = GetRange(line2Func(x), baseFunc(x), out maxY);

        for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; ++y)
            yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), x, y);
    }
}

private static int GetRange(float y1, float y2, out int maxY)
{
    if (y1 < y2)
    {
        maxY = Mathf.FloorToInt(y2);
        return Mathf.CeilToInt(y1);
    }

    maxY = Mathf.FloorToInt(y1);
    return Mathf.CeilToInt(y2);
}

private static Func<int, float> CreateFunc<T>(T pt1, T pt2)
    where T : IPoint
{
    var y0 = pt1.y;

    if (y0 == pt2.y)
        return x => y0;

    float m = (float)(pt2.y - y0) / (pt2.x - pt1.x);

    return x => m * (x - pt1.x) + y0;
}

    public static float TriangleArea<T>(T p1, T p2, T p3)
        where T : IPoint
    {
        float a, b, c;

        if (!CheckIfValidTriangle(p1, p2, p3, out a, out b, out c))
            return 0;

        return TriangleArea(a, b, c);
    }

    public static float TriangleArea(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        // Thanks to: http://james-ramsden.com/area-of-a-triangle-in-3d-c-code/

        float s = (a + b + c) / 2.0f;
        return Mathf.Sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
    }

    public static Point GetTriangleCenter<T>(T p0, T p1, T p2)
        where T : IPoint
    {
        // Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524755/finding-center-of-2d-triangle

        return new Point(p0.x + p1.x + p2.x / 3, p0.y + p1.y + p2.y / 3);
    }

    public static bool CheckIfValidTriangle<T>(T v1, T v2, T v3, out float a, out float b, out float c)
        where T : IPoint
    {
        a = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(v1.x, v1.y), new Vector2(v2.x, v2.y));
        b = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(v2.x, v2.y), new Vector2(v3.x, v3.y));
        c = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(v3.x, v3.y), new Vector2(v1.x, v1.y));

        if (a + b <= c || a + c <= b || b + c <= a)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

`IPoint` interface could be a good point for own `Point` implementations (for libs like `Clipper, TessDotNet or Poly2Tri`). You can change it at any time (two `UnityEngine.Vector2` or `System.Drawing.Point`).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** I solved all bugs here:

Also I answered my own question asking this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734816/3286975